# enable screenshots feature of failed tests in testfx

Tags: testing, javafx, integration-testing, testfx

I'm currently building tests for a JavaFX app with [TestFX](http://testfx.github.io/TestFX/) with it's following versions :

- testfx-core 4.0.1-alpha
- testfx-junit 4.0.1-alpha

There is not much information about how to enable screeshot taking feature for failed tests and in case it is enabled by default where they are stored ?

Comment: have a look at DebugUtils: it comes with a bunch of methods to tailor the error output, including screenshot (not entirely certain whether that's available in 4.01, mine is something like 4.0.14 with a couple of tweaks ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's very simple to add a screenshot to the failure message (or tailor the message to your needs in any way): the support resides in `org.testfx.util.DebugUtils`, f.i. `saveScreenshot()` takes a screenshot on failure and stores it at the default location (that's the path to the top-level project folder)

```
verifyThat(myNode, myMatcher, saveScreenshot());
```

The path is configurable by providing a custom Supplier for Path, f.i. (for win)

```
verifyThat(myNode, myMatcher, 
            saveScreenshot((() -> Path.of("C:\\Temp\\testfailures", "mytest.png")), ""));
```

Not entirely certain about version dependencies: 4.0.1 is a bit oldish (from Mar 2015), current is 4.0.15 (from Oct 2018), mine is 4.0.14 (from Aug 2018).

Comment: I do not know if it is because of my version of testfx but i can get a failed test screenshot even with the default path. That's wierd!? I saw from souce code that the tests hava a test-fx prefix in the name of generated png. I cant find any in my file system

Comment: look at the error message of the failed test: it has a line that prints the complete (absolute) path to the image file

Comment: I have no errors indicating a screenshot or a path of anything!. Maybe, it has something to do with the version i'm currently using

Comment: maybe, can't say - but you are certain that the test fails?